# I'm trying to round the decimal values by using round in liquid. But round didn't work

Tags: liquid

I have tried to round up the float value using round as referred in the document(https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/round/).

Here is the code

```
{% assign my_integer = 0.346257 | times: 100 %}
<span>{{ my_integer | round: 2 }} %</span>
```

But it results me like

```
34.625699999999995 %
```

I'm trying to display like 35 %. I don't know why round is not working.

Comment: even I tried ceil like( {{ 2.0 | ceil }} ). But It is also not working. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment the following:

`{% assign my_integer = 0.346257 | times: 100 %}
<span>{{ my_integer | round: 2 }} %</span>`

Returns for me: `34.63 %` I don't how you get `34.625699999999995 %` instead.

If you like to get only `35%` you should write it as `| round` no need for the 2 after it, since that says how many numbers after the decimal point will the rounding start:

`{% assign my_integer = 0.346257 | times: 100 %}
<span>{{ my_integer | round }} %</span>`

Comment: Yes I knew 2 is not need that I can understand. As you said I even didn't know why it's return me like    34.625699999999995 %

Isn't be the version issue that I guess ?

Comment: I aslo created the issue in shopify github. Here is the link
https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/1013